# Eclipse plugin development: Vertically scrolling table?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, swt

I'm trying to create a vertically scrolling table within a dialog, without success.  When I create the table, it auto-expands to whatever height it needs to be regardless of screen size/resolution.  Lots of data creates a table that extends well below the bottom of the screen.

My code goes something like this (not verbatim, may be a type-o or two):

```
final Table table = new Table(parent, SWT.SINGLE | 
  SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.SCROLL_LINE | borderStyle | orientation );
table.setHeaderVisible(true);
table.setLinesVisible(true);

TableViewer tableView = new TableViewer(table);

// code yanked to set up the columns (movable == false, 
// resiable == true, with set text, widths, and toolTipText)

tableView.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
// BeanLabelProvider's getColumnText returns the beanDescriptor's
// getReadMethod.invoke().toString()
tableView.setLabelProvider(new BeanLableProvider(MyClass.class));
tableView.setInput(anArrayOfMyClass);
```

All this code lives in my dialog class's createDialogArea().

At any rate, I've tried the following:

1. `treeView.setItemCount()` trims the data, it doesn't limit the amount of data displayed.
2. `table.getVerticalBar()` returns a valid `ScrollBar`, and that `scrollbar.getVisible() == true;`?!  Really?  Prove it.  Didn't think so.  `setVisible(true)` does nothing.
3. `table.setBounds()`?  Nope.  Even after I call `layout()` and/or `redraw()`.
4. The above was done within `createDialogArea()`.  If I call `setBounds()` within MyDialog.initializeBounds() it shrinks the table and adds **scrollbars** (gasp!), but the dialog doesn't resize.  Calling `table.getParent().layout(true)` resizes the table, not the dialog.  Augh!
5. In initBounds, I have the following code:

   ```
   Shell shell = getShell();
   shell.setBounds(foo, bar, baz qux);
   myTable.setBounds(foo, bar, baz-fudgeX, qux-fudgeY);
   myTable.getVerticalBar().setVisible(true); // see, it wasn't null!
   // this line doesn't seem to have any effect, I can comment it out and have
   // the same apparent result.
   shell.layout(true);
   // If I call shell.pack() the table snaps back to its original size (huge).
   ```

Without the call to `pack()`, the okay/cancel buttons are clipped off the bottom of the dialog.  With it, the entire exercise is a moot point.

Why do I get the feeling I'm missing something Really Basic that'll make me want to smack my forehead when someone else points it out?

Comment: And once I have this working, I need to make the cells all editable and bind them to the bean in question.  Whee.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What layout do you use for your `Shell`? Most layouts simply ask the controls for their preferred size, during a call of `layout()`. The preferred size of your Table is the size, where all rows can be displayed. If there's no more constraints, the layout resizes the Shell to that preferred size, which is not what you want.

To prevent this, you'll need to set a height hint for your layout on your Table. An example for that is this [snippet](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet38.java?view=co). If you remove the line

```
data.heightHint = 200;
```

the resulting Shell is way too high.

Comment: Spot on.  Many thanks.  As in the snippet, I whipped up a gridlayout for the table, and created a GridData with a heightHint, and it worked like a charm.  Thanks again.

Comment: I was under the mistaken impression that size hints were minimums.  Thanks for setting me straight.